# Gesture in multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, gesture, swrevealviewcontroller, pan

I have used `SWRevealViewController` for slide menu feature and I added a gesture recognizer so that I can see the slide menu. I succeed in this with the following lines.

```
detail.target = revealViewController()
detail.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```

detail is the bar button which also show the slide menu

Now I have 4 tabs and I want each tab to has the button and the gesture.
I set up all swift files(of tabs) with the above code and it works 
BUT!

Here is my problem, for example:
I start with the first tab I use the gesture it works; I go to the second tab the gesture also works; if I go back to first tab the gesture doesn't work!!

The button always works! (i used to all tabs copy-paste the code!)

Any help? :D

Comment: In which method you have wrote the code of add gesture?

Comment: Inside the viewDidLoad and inside 
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
}|

Comment: When you remove the gesture?

Comment: Are you removing gesture ?

Comment: no only add it first to viewdidload and when this didn't work i erase the code from viewdidload and put it to loadview (i did nothing to storyboard i only add the line of code view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer()))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your question where i put the code i realize that viewDidLoad only runs the first time so i put the code inside viewdidappear like this:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```

and everything is fine and works perfectly now :)

Comment: @Payal Maniyar thnx ;)